# The minimum three elements from two tuples of size 3

Tags: algorithms

If I have two tuples `(a1,b1,c1)` and `(a2,b2,c2)`, where we know each is ordered from smallest to largest, how would I return a tuple that takes the minimum elements from both tuples and orders them from least to largest?

I tried to break down the problem for two tuples so:
`a1, b1` and `a2, b2` are two tuples and we can do

```
if a1 < a2:
    if a2 < b1:
        return (a1, a2)
    else:
        return (a1, b1)
else:
   # similar for case above
```

But when there are 3 elements it's confusing me, so if anyone can help out I'd highly appreciate it. I don't want to try any sorting and instead use inequalities.

Comment: You *can* solve this by exploring all of the decision tree. Can you take shortcuts comparing a1 and c2 first? What about b1&b2, c1&a2?

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. It would seem numbered tuples and "lettered" elements confuse me.